# maintain aws lex chat communication on all pages of website

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, chatbot, amazon-lex

I have created a chatbot using AWS lex and Lambda. Bot works as expected. I have store the slot data into **sessionAttributes**. The issue I am facing is when I communicate with bot from my website and if I open another tab of my site, it does't show the previous chat which happened in older tab(here both tabs are open).

On every new tab chat starts from start.

Requirement is to continue from where it was left in previous tab.

Am I missing any flow here ? I have gone though  AWS doc but didn't get any clear picture to do the same. Any example of the same will help better.

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the chat into some database of your own. On page load, you need to fetch the chat of current session or current user (based on your requirement).
 That way even if the user refreshes the page or open up a new tab, he will be able to see the chat he already had with the chatbot.